# Why does the MOSFET Vds vs. Id graph stop at a certain point?

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Why does the Vgs=15V line stop at around Vds = 3V?  Is it just because the behaviour can be guessed by seeing the lower Vgs lines, or does the MOSFET not work at Vds>3?

This is from the [IRFZ44N datasheet.](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFZ44N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d)

Comment: The transistor is conducting around 150A at the point where that curve ends. What is its absolute maximum current rating?

Comment: @asker Friendly reminder: If one of the answers below answered your question, don't forget to click the green check mark to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [IRFZ44N](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/n-channel/irfz44n/) has a maximum *pulsed* drain current I<sub>DM</sub> of 160 A:

[image]

That fits well with your graph...

[image]

Note the maximum *continuous* drain current I<sub>D</sub> is much lower. Figure 11 in the linked datasheet explains how they arrive at the maximum pulsed current.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just because the behaviour can be guessed [?]

Yes. The device gets driven past its ratings and is degraded and/or destroyed :)

Now, jokes aside, for some very high-pulse-capable devices, it may be hard to experimentally measure things. That's rare, though. Normally, the graphs just end where you should stop if you were to apply it in a circuit and get a higher rated device as well.